# Classification of singularities - $f(z)=z \cos(1/z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I have to classify the singularity at the origin of the function $f(z)=z \cos(1/z)$. How do I get this answer without passing through the Laurent serie directly (in using **(*)**). Is anyone could help me at this point?

I think this is an essential singularities because of the behavior of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the Taylor serie of $cos$ in $f$.

**(*)** **Definition :**  An isolated singularity is essential if the Laurent serie contain an infinite number of term $(z-z_0)^k$, $k < 0$.

Comment: Using Laurent series is probably the easiest solution for this.

Comment: If you approach zero along the imaginary axis, the values are very infinite, while the values along the real axis have zero limit. It seems to me that no pole behaves this way. Isn’t this enough for an argument that the singularity is essential?

Comment: @HenryW. Are you able to develop this serie, because I got a bit of difficulties to do it (the 1/z probably)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \cos z^{-1} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j z^{-2j}}{(2j)!} = \sum_{j=-\infty}^0 \frac{(-1)^j z^{2j}}{(-2j)!}
$$
so $z \cos z^{-1}$ has a essential singularity at $0$.

You can also use Riemann's theorem to prove it.